# A bad loop or incorrect syntax while writing csv?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to record the output or X and Y coordinates of my mouse position using pyautogui and write them to a csv file. Whenever I run my code it prints out X and Y in separate columns so that's good but then on the top left under X it says 'True' and then one row down under the Y column it also says 'True'. I am really not understanding why this is happening.

```
import pyautogui, sys
import numpy as np
import csv

try:
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n')

while True:
    with open('Mousemovement.csv', mode = 'w') as csv_file:
        fieldnames = ['X', 'Y']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames = fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'X': x in pyautogui.position()})
        writer.writerow({'Y': y in pyautogui.position()})
```

Comment: this: `x in pyautogui.position()` is either `True` or `False` ... why do print it like this?

Answer (score 1):

```
x in pyautogui.position()
```

uses the Python `in` operator. This is tests for `membership` - basically, does `x` exist in `pyautogui.position()`. This returns a `boolean` value (`True` or `False`). This value is then written to your CSV file.

In addition, you are calling `writerow` twice per loop, which is why your Y values are appearing below X.

Finally, you are opening and writing your CSV file multiple times. You should only be opening it once, writing the headers, then going into the loop to write the values.

You just need to rewrite your code like so:

```
with open('Mousemovement.csv', mode = 'w') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['X', 'Y']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames = fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position() # Get the position into x and y
        writer.writerow({'X': x, 'Y': y}) # Pass a single dictionary, so one row is printed
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I'm trying to do this with the code snippet you suggested but I'm just getting a blank csv file now. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: I noticed another problem - try the updated code in the answer.